# Google Custom Search encodes spaces with %2520

Tags: encoding, whitespace, google-custom-search

I am using the free version of Google Custom Search. The 2-page version.

They gave me 1 javascript for the search box, and one for the search results page.

It seems fine, except that spaces in the request get converted to `%2520` instead of `%20`, which leads to 0 results.

If I write my OWN simple HTML form that points to the result page, it works fine (it uses '+' for spaces).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. 
It was found that the url was rewritten to another one which resulted in extra encoding of the query term.

In my case, www.sub.domain.com/?q=some text  was redirected (301) to sub.domain.com/?q=some%2520text 
It was an error in usage. The link should not have contained 'www' for a sub domain.

Avoiding the redirection fixed the issue. Check if your query link is getting rewritten/redirected.